# Manage RabbitMQ consumers

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I am planning to write a log processing application using RabbitMQ, Symfony2 and the RabbitMqBundle.
The tool I am working on has to be highly available and must process millions of entries per day, so it's important that the consumers are always up and running (short breaks are fine), otherwise my queue might overflow after a while.

Are there best practices on how to manage the consumers (written in PHP), start/restart them in case of an error etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this bash script to make sure that there are all required consumers running on [imagepush.to](http://imagepush.to):

```
#!/bin/bash

NB_TASKS=1
SYMFONY_ENV="prod"

TEXT[0]="app/console rabbitmq:consumer primary"
TEXT[1]="app/console rabbitmq:consumer secondary"

for text in "${TEXT[@]}"
do

NB_LAUNCHED=$(ps ax | grep "$text" | grep -v grep | wc -l)

TASK="/usr/bin/env php ${text} --env=${SYMFONY_ENV}"

for (( i=${NB_LAUNCHED}; i<${NB_TASKS}; i++ ))
do
  echo "$(date +%c) - Launching a new consumer"
  nohup $TASK &
done

done
```

If I remember correctly I took base from KnpBundles code.

Comment: If i see correctly, the script only starts the consumers, but it does not handle the case of a dead consumer, it does not respawn it.

Comment: For this I set a cron task to run this script every minute to make sure it always work.

Comment: I also gave supervisord a try, it looks pretty well, it respawns the rabbitmq consumers in case they die etc. http://edvanbeinum.com/how-to-install-and-configure-supervisord/

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of such tools (`god` is another one). I think I answered your initial question, so I would appreciate if you choose it as best answer. :)

Comment: @AntonBabenko, do you have any similar solution for windows?

Comment: Sorry, there is no windows in my life :)

Comment: I also use supervisord and it works great for restarting crashed workers automatically.

Answer (score 0):

## Stop consumer

To stop your consumer with name `my_consumer` use

```
kill `ps aux | less | grep 'rabbitmq:consumer my_consumer' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

1. `ps aux | less | grep 'rabbitmq:consumer my_consumer'` - will find all running processes of the consumer
2. `grep -v grep` - will exclude your own search process
3. `awk '{print $2}'` - get only process id from the row
4. `kill` - will terminate all found processes

## Start consumer

To start your consumer with name `my_consumer` use

```
nohup /usr/bin/env php app/console rabbitmq:consumer consumer --env=prod &
```

I have a lot of consumers in the project and it became hard to restart them after deploy. And I started using [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/overview/what-is-capistrano/) + [Symfony plugin](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/) to deploy my project. I wrote a few custom tasks to start/stop/restart the consumers based on the yaml config. Tasks are based on the commands from above.