How to stop or timeout a consumer from consuming after specific time in RabbitMQ using php
Here is a hello world example on rabbitmq docs about consumer using php and php-amqplib package:
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

echo " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n";

$callback = function ($msg) {
    echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->getBody(), "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

try {
    $channel->consume();
} catch (\Throwable $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();


Are there any ways to stop or timeout the consumer after a specific time?
And I wonder how the process can reach the close() method of connection and channel in the code above if there are not any exception occur because the consume() method is blocking it?
I found out that there is a basic_cancel method but I don know where and when to use it because like I said, the consume() method is blocking the code.

A consumer is a process which should normally never end. You could run another task sending a sigstop. In other words: get the pid and run a shell script with sleep and kill. But I would consider as bad practice, because it could be killed during processing.

Thank your @MarkusZeller. So I should always keep consumer alive as long as possible. But If I want to terminate the consumer, the possible ways is kill the process or throw exception and the code go to the catch block -> reach close channel and conection block -> end of file -> exit, right?

I don't know any other elegant way. Like Symfony supports php bin/console messenger:stop-workers --env=prod, which also kills them all.

Found another interesting post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793839/manage-rabbitmq-consumers

The callback function could execute $msg->getChannel()->stopConsume();.

You could modify the callback function to react to an message 'quit'. With an second script you could send the quit message to the queue.
$callback = function ($msg) {
    echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->getBody(), "\n";
    // Send a message with the string "quit" to cancel the consumer.
    if ($msg->getBody() === 'quit') {
        $msg->getChannel()->basic_cancel($msg->getConsumerTag());
    }
}

